# Problem with Adafruit_SSD1306 library in .h fie

Tags: stm32, oled

I have a project which includes OLED display, so I decided to use Adafruit_SSD1306 library. But I have problem with compiling code, which uses this library, in another .h file.

When I use this library in .ino file, everythings works, but in OLED.h file I get this error:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Multiple libraries found "DallasTemperature.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library-master
Multiple libraries found "OneWire.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\Documents\Arduino\libraries\OneWire-master
Multiple libraries found "SPI.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\STM32\hardware\stm32\1.8.0\libraries\SPI
Multiple libraries found "Wire.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\STM32\hardware\stm32\1.8.0\libraries\Wire
Multiple libraries found "Adafruit_GFX.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_GFX_Library
Multiple libraries found "Adafruit_SSD1306.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306
Multiple libraries found "SrcWrapper.h"
 Used: C:\Users\luky\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\STM32\hardware\stm32\1.8.0\libraries\SrcWrapper
Byly nalezené násobné knihovny "Adafruit_I2CDevice.h"
 Použitý: C:\Users\luky\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO
```

The error is from this piece of code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

TwoWire Wire1(PB9, PB8); // Use STM32´s I2C2

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
```

STM32 Bluepill board is used.

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem, but using `#include` after any code or variable declarations is not good coding practice. Put all `#includes` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks thats good note.

Comment: But its still dont works

Comment: Sorry for that ... did you check if you installed multiple same-named libraries (maybe different versions?). Try to compile some sample sketches to see if something is wrong in your own code or within the libraries installation.

Comment: Sample sketches compile correctly, also when I use the library in my .ino file, everythings works correctly. Only problem is that my code is very long and it would be very jumble to include all the display code into this main (.ino) file. So I triing to write display code into another .h and .cpp file and then include it into the main file. But that´s the point where I get the compilation error.

Comment: Did you use `#ifndef ___H` checks for not including the same include file twice? (it should not matter for your errors, but something to check).

Comment: Yes, I used..
`#ifndef __OLED__`
`#define __OLED__`

 `#endif`

Comment: You also could check if you can find multiple equally named libraries somewhere on your computer and remove them (after making a backup)

Comment: I also tried that. There is just the 1 library. Its very strange problem xD

Comment: Than I'm out of ideas ... maybe someone with experience with one of these libraries can answer.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks for help Michel Keijzers

Comment: Maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkNkpzy8TbY helps?

Comment: It looks like for some reason it can't find `Adafruit_I2CDevice.h` which is part of `Adafruit_BusIO`, which is supposed to be automatically installed when you install `Adafruit_SSD1306`. Try to install it either via Library Manager on IDE or download it from [Adafruit_BusIO](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BusIO). Personally I dislike anything from Adafruit, it is bloated and you ask for a money they gives you the entire jungle with all the dependencies loaded. There are much simpler SSD1602 library out there.